# Date appearing as number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

Hello I am very new to JavaScript and have a probably obviously noob question.

When I write this:

```
<script>
    var curdate = new Date();
    document.write(curdate.setFullYear(1989, 07, 26));
</script>
```

I get the date shown as a number like : `620154050573` and not as a normal date display. I have tried converting it to a string first but same thing happens.

Please explain.

Comment: Don’t print it with the `setFullYear` method. Set the year, then, as the next step, print `curdate`.

Comment: As the [specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setFullYear) clearly states, `setFullYear` *"Returns new timestamp"*, not a **date object** !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

JavaScript Date objects are based on a time value that is the number of milliseconds since 1 January, 1970 UTC.

If you want to format a Date object you can use one of the Date object methods. [MDN Data.prototype documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/prototype).

In the example below I used the the toUTCString method, but take a look at the link above and find the method that works best for you.

```
<script>
  var curdate = new Date();
  curdate.setFullYear(1989, 07, 26)
  document.write(curdate.toUTCString());
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of `setFullYear` is a `Number`, not a `Date`.

```
var curdate = new Date();
curdate.setFullYear(1989, 07, 26)
document.write(curdate);
```

Also, keep in mind that prefixing a number with `0` tells JS to treat that number as octal.

Answer (score 0):

Just call setFullYear(), then display the date instead. E.g.

```
curdate.setFullYear(1989, 7, 26);
console.log(curdate);
```

The setFullYear function returns a number:

> Return Value:     A Number, representing the number of milliseconds
>   between the date object and midnight January 1 1970

From the documentation:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setfullyear.asp